# Replace and Update Input tags with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello I am trying to collect event data from a my school event web page and save to a list based on locations. However there is no current event information on the page since school is closed. So I tried to get the tags that take the user specified dates and change those values. So that I can make url request with the new tags and get event data from the year before. However doing this does not give me any new information. How do I replace an old input tag with a new one, and how do I update the html page with these new tags. Attached below is example code of what I am doing.

```
response = requests.get(url)

#start and end dates I want to use
st_date = "04/01/2019"
ed_date = "04/14/2019"

soup = bs(response.text, 'html.parser')

input_list = soup.findAll('input')

#the first and second values in the list are the input tags
start_date = input_list[0]
end_date = input_list[1]

#replace the value attribute with date strings
start_date['value'] = st_date
end_date['value'] = en_date

#insert the new tags
soup.insert(1,start_date)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do - but if you want to get different page then you have to use changed `url`. Get original `url` and see how it change for different values in form and then create new url with own values.

Comment: BTW: if you use `requests` and `BS` then you work with HTML in your memory and it can't change `HTML` on server and you can't force server to load new data. You have to change values in url which you use in `requests` to load different page. And probably you will have to use `requests.post(url, data=new_data)` and probably you may have to test page using `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox (tab: Network) to see what url is loaded when page send form data, and what data it sends to server.

Answer (score 0):

You're manipulating a static copy of the web page. Instead you should choose one of two options to achieve your goal:

1. Use Selenium or something equivalent that will execute any JavaScript code that observes form field changes, or will handle injected submit/update button clicks.
2. Open the Developer Tools in your browser (usually F12) and watch the Network tab for outgoing requests when you change the dates. Then call these endpoints with your desired dates and get the events data from the response.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to change the content of html/xml using BeautifulSoup. You can also do that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = BeautifulSoup(some_html, 'html.parser')
html.find('tag').string = 'some new value'
```

Last line will change the content of html page.